# Why doesn't the value in for loop change?

Tags: python

Why does the value of `range(len(whole)/2)` not change after `whole` is modified? And what do you call `range(len...)` value in for-loop?

```
whole = 'selenium'
for i in range(len(whole)/2):
    print whole
    whole = whole[1:-1]
```

output:

```
selenium
eleniu
leni
en
```

Answer (score 8):

The `range()` produces a list of integers *once*. That list is then iterated over by the `for` loop. It is not re-created each iteration; that'd be very inefficient.

You could use a `while` loop instead:

```
i = 0
while i < (len(whole) / 2):
    print whole
    whole = whole[1:-1]
    i += 1
```

the `while` condition is re-tested each loop iteration.

Answer (score 3):

The range function creates a list

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

And the for loop iterates over the value of the list.

The list is not recreated each and every time

But this is not the case in normal list

```
wq=[1,2,3]

for i in wq:
    if 3 in wq:
        wq.remove(3)
    print i

1
2
```